# What's equivalent to TRUNCATE TABLE in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm looking for something equivalent to [TRUNCATE TABLE](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqltruncate.html)

How I do this using SQL Server 2005?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: TRUNCATE TABLE will not work in SQL 2005?

Comment: I don't understand. you can also use TRUNCATE TABLE in sql-server. is there a problem?

Comment: Well,for me it seems not works, I get this error:`The TRUNCATE TABLE SQL construct or statement is not supported.`

Comment: What's the exact SQL your trying to execute?

Comment: `SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand(); ... myCmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE loginDetails";`

Comment: @TheMask: How are you executing it?

Comment: @TheMask: What permissions does the user that you are executing the command with have?  TRUNCATE requires more permissions than just standard DELETE on the table.

Comment: Well, first I tried by C# code - not worked. and then I tried by visual csharp.

Comment: this does seem like a permissions issue. From the msdn article i linked: The minimum permission required is ALTER on table_name. TRUNCATE TABLE permissions default to the table owner, members of the sysadmin fixed server role, and the db_owner and db_ddladmin fixed database roles, and are not transferable. However, you can incorporate the TRUNCATE TABLE statement within a module, such as a stored procedure, and grant appropriate permissions to the module using the EXECUTE AS clause

Comment: why downvoted my and Gary.S post's?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

t-sql for sql server 2005:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE schema.tablename;
GO
```

link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much :) The problem was in permissions.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK TRUNCATE TABLE works in server 2005 (just tried it to make sure) so just consider this an alternative, but still not sure why you don't want to use it.

Did you try

```
DELETE FROM TABLE
```

or

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE 1=1 --SQL server may warn no expression in the previous one
```

Comment: Unlike TRUNCATE, this will put all of the deleted rows into the transaction log, which might not be desired.

Comment: @Joe Yeah that's true. I'm not sure why he doesn't want to use truncate table though AFAIK it works....

Comment: I'm not saying he should do this, I'm just saying this is the only other alternative I know of, no real reason not to use Truncate but to each his own.